# MySQL insert multiple rows from explode

Tags: php, mysql, vbulletin

I have a variable

```
$allnames = 'John,Peter,Maya';
```

and I am trying to check if each name exists in the `user` table, and if it exists I want insert each name into one row in another table.

```
$allnames = 'John,Peter,Maya';
$names = explode(",", $allnames);

foreach($names as $name)
{
    $checkusers = $db->query_read("SELECT username,userid FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . " `user` WHERE username = '".$name."' "); 
    $results = $db->fetch_array($checkusers);

    $db->query_write("INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . " `invite_users` (username)  VALUES ('".$results['userid']."') 
"); 

}
```

The solution :

```
$string = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userstag']);
$arr = explode(",",$string);

$sql = $db->query_read("SELECT username FROM  " . TABLE_PREFIX . " `user` WHERE username IN ('".implode("', '", $arr) . "')");

while($r = $db->fetch_array($sql))
{    
    $sqli = $db->query_write("INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . " invite_users (username) VALUES ('".$r['username']."') 
    ");     
}
```

Comment: You need to check for and return sql errors. There is no way that is valid sql if `TABLE_PREFIX` isn't a space or empty string.

Comment: Is this `mysqli`, PDO or something else? You're exposed to severe problems here because of two [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because none of your values are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: @tadman , it is `MYSQL`

Comment: What database driver are you using? I'm not sure where `query_write` comes from or what `$db` refers to.

Comment: @tadman , thanks brother I tried until I was able to found The solution and i added it above ... it is `vbulletin database`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code , if the issue is with spiting of the variable

```
$allnames = 'John,Peter,Maya';
$arr = explode(",",$allnames);
$name_1=$arr[0];
$name_2=$arr[1];
$name_3=$arr[3];
```